# Problem running Lucius using Wine

Tags: wine, games

My problem is I can not run Lucious properly on my computer, I have installed the latest drivers for my graphics card (GeForce GT430 2GB) and in the game called *Lucius*, in WINE, I get this error:

> **Error**
>
> Can't set new display mode: RESET_DEVICE_RESET_FAILED
>   Cant' set old display mode: RESET_DEVICE_RESET_FAILED

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`According to WineHQ`](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14624) Lucius unless you are trying to run it via Steam using Wine is rated **Garbage**.

That means that the game will not run in Wine properly or wont run at all.

By the screenshot it looks like you have copy of the game installed, not via Steam, installing the game via Steam would mean you need to buy the game again and risk encountering further issues.

Comment: You mean I can not install copies "unoriginal" game on my pc using ubuntu?
Excuse my ignorance is the first time you use Ubuntu but I love this OS and I keep him.

Comment: Well, that is not for discussion here, I dont care where the copy of the game came from as long as you dont tell me where it did. What I am saying is that the retail version of the game will not run on Wine, the Steam version of the game might.

Comment: Sorry if I bother with my question was not my intention, I'm new here and new to ubuntu, greetings and thanks.

Comment: @JavierJara You bothered no one, really. Feel free to use and abuse the site. Well do our best to help.